# Possible factorizations of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

I am given the equation $x^3-2x^2-3x=0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{12}$
and I have found the roots of the polynomial to be {$0,3,5,8,9,11$}$\subset \mathbb{Z}_{12}$.

Now, I am trying to find all the different possible factorizations of this polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. My initial idea was to just mash roots together into a product of 3 linear terms, and I got that $x(x-5)(x-11)$ has the exact same roots as the original polynomial.

When I tried this a second time, with $x(x-8)(x-11)$, I obtained the set of roots {$0,2,3,6,8,11$}, so this contradicts my idea...

What should I think about when trying to approach this problem?

Comment: That polynomial splits completely over the integers, and the factorization there will also be a factorization over ${\bf Z}_{12}$.

Comment: Anyway, if you multiply out either of the "factorizations" that you found, you don't get the original polynomial, so neither one is correct.

Comment: $x^3-2x^2-3x=x(x^2-2x-3)=x(x-3)(x+1)$

Comment: Are you saying that all polynomials have exactly one factorizations?

Comment: Over something like $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$?  Absolutely not.  $x^2+8$ is both $(x+10)(x+2)$ and $(x+4)(x+8)$.

Comment: Is there an algorithmic way to find these?

Comment: Over a finite ring, there are only finitely many possibilities to check, so there is certainly an algorithmic way: just systematically try every possibilitiy, and keep the ones that work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is in response to Jungleshrimp's question aboout Randall's comment.]

Let's look at the question of finding all ways to factor $x^2+8$ over ${\bf Z}_{12}$. From $x^2+8\equiv(x-r)(x-s)$, we get the system $r+s\equiv0$, $rs\equiv8$ (where all congruences are to the modulus 12). Eliminating $s$, we get $-r^2\equiv8$, which is $r^2\equiv4$, which has the solutions $r\equiv2,4,8,10$, leading to $s\equiv10,8,4,2$, respectively. And this leads to the two factorizations in the comment by @Randall.